Why set payload of Mock when via Expression mode works but via literal mode failed
strong textWhy set payload of Mock when via Expression mode works
but via literal mode failed with error below, I though it should support both ways.
expression mode
<munit-tools:payload value="#[500]" />

literal mode
<munit-tools:payload value='"500"' />

error
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#a7e9d32' of type 
[org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.config.dsl.parameter.
TopLevelParameterObjectFactory_ByteBuddy_CallingSuperGetObjectType]
while setting bean property 'parameters' with key [<<payload>>];
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#a7e9d32': FactoryBean threw 
exception on object creation; nested exception is org.mule.runtime.core.
api.config.ConfigurationException: Element '"500"' is not defined 
in the Mule Registry


Please add xml code snippets along with images.

Don't use images for Mule applications&configurations. Use the XML representation, pasted as text in the question and formatted with [code block]. For errors & logs also use [code block] format, specially if the original is a multi line messages. One line long messages are harder to read.

added code snippets already

Add the content of mock_totalElements.dwl too.

thanks for hints, I will update my question now

@aled, it seems set payload of Mock when via Expression mode  works but via literal mode fails .
